# Pytorch dataloader with iterable dataset stops after one epoch in multiprocessing mode

Tags: multiprocessing, dataset, pytorch, iterable, dataloader

I have a dataloader that is initialised with a iterable dataset. I found that when I use multiprocessing (i.e. num_workers>0 in DataLoader) in dataloader, once the dataloader is exhausted after one epoch, it doesn't get reset automatically when I iterate it again in the second epoch. Below is a small reproducible example.

I am aware that "Workers are shut down once the end of the iteration is reached," according to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#multi-process-data-loading). However, I would like to know how to achieve my expected behaviour of "resetting automatically". Thanks for any help in advance!

```py
import torch
class MyIterableDataset(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        super().__init__()
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(range(self.start, self.end))

    
dataset = MyIterableDataset(0, 4)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=False, num_workers=1, drop_last=False)


for epoch in range(2):
    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader):
        print(i, data)

"""
stdout:
0 tensor([0, 1])
1 tensor([2, 3])
2 _IterableDatasetStopIteration(worker_id=0)
"""
```

While my expectation of stdout is

```
"""
0 tensor([0, 1])
1 tensor([2, 3])
0 tensor([0, 1])
1 tensor([2, 3])
"""
```

I am using the latest pytorch version (1.6.0)

Comment: It works on my machine! Are you using the latest pytorch?

Comment: @hkchengrex I am using pytorch version 1.4.0, are you using 1.6.0?

Comment: Yes, I am :) I cannot find related changelog though.

Comment: @hkchengrex I updated my pytorch version to 1.6.0, however, I am getting the same behaviour

Comment: That's really weird. I just copied your code and got your "expected" result. I am also using Python 3.7 if that matters.

Comment: @hkchengrex Yeah, it's really weird, I am using Python 3.6 under Debian GNU/Linux 9. I am not sure whether it is because of the OS-specific behaviour of multiprocessing module. Thanks anyway for looking into this!